# Wrapper for Jaxx

Tags: android, jaxx, ios, api-design

I would like to build android or iOS application that can send and receive data with contract. I can simply use JAXX, which can let me send 'data' to the contract.

But the only problem is that I have to manually punch in data(e.g. put it arguments in order manually). For example, if I'm making a gambling contract or game contract, and mobile devices need to send data. In this case, it would be easier for users to simply click 'play' button and automatically send data and eth. Or it would be hard for users to type in all of those data manually. For ordinary users, it would be a hassle.

But in order to customize it, I need to either have the entire source code of JAXX(android version or iOS version) or some kind of APIs.

I looked up the website and it has source code. But it seems it is only written in javascript. So what would be the best way to approach this problem?